# I am trying to pull the date and time from a specifically formatted string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the date and day and time from a specifically formatted date string in python.

Here is what the string looks like that I need to parse:

```
Last Update: Tue 04 May, 09:56 PM
```

I tried this code and it didn't work:

```
import re

# Open the file that you want to search
f = open("scan_results2.txt", "r")

# Will contain the entire content of the file as a string
content = f.read()

# The regex pattern that we created
pattern = "\d{2}[/ ]\d{2}[/ ]\d{4}"

# Will return all the strings that are matched
dates = re.findall(pattern, content)
print(str(dates))
```

Please let me know how to do this properly.

Comment: Does the line always start with "Last Update:"?

Comment: Try `Last Update: *(.+)`

Comment: Should `09:S6` be `09:56`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes it does

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes it should be 09:56

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: you mean: pattern = "Last Update: *(.+)" ?

Comment: Yes, the pattern itself.

Comment: Did it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line is always in the same format, like if it always starts with "Last Update:" and always has the date/time in the same format, then you don't need to use a regex at all.

You can just use `datetime.strptime()` to parse the *entire* thing into a `datetime` object.

```
from datetime import datetime

with open("scan_results2.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read().strip()

    dateVal = datetime.strptime(content, "Last Update: %a %d %B, %I:%M %p")

    # Your date format didn't have a year set
    # If you want to do that, you can do:
    # dateVal = dateVal.replace(year=2021)
    print(dateVal)
```

Comment: I got this error: raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '[INFO] 0.2088: Ali Abdulsattar Ali Almussa\n[INFO] 0.9169: 1130137324\n[INFO] 0.3198: توكلنا\n[INFO] 0.1072: No record ofinfection\n[INFO] 0.0018: Last Update: Tuc 04 May, 09:S6 PM' does not match format 'Last Update: %a %d %B, %I:%M %p'

Comment: @ironmantis7x I didn't realize there could be multiple lines or that the lines started with `[INFO]`.  Maybe this code could be adapted to each line and have a `try`/`except` added to filter out non-date lines.